# How to create a message box when user press on an image in swift ?

Tags: swift, button, tags

I am trying to do something like this picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JneD.png

So when a user press at a specific area in a box, a button or a message tag will appear.

Any idea where should I start from? I was able to create the box, just need when the user press a tag appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `UIImageView` to your view controller. Set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to true for the image view. Attach a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the image view.

In the handler for the tap gesture recognizer's tap handler, call `location(in:)` to get the coordinates of the tap in the image view's coordinate system.

Use the `CGRect` function `contains(_:)` to determine if the tap point is inside either of those areas.

Note that alternately you could simply add transparent buttons on top of your image view at the desired locations and use target/actions on those buttons to respond to the taps.